# LLVM: How do I write IR to file and run it?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to parse an IR file created with `clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp -o test.ir` using the `parseIRFile` call, manipulate this IR a bit, and then write the IR back to a file.

I've tried using the `WriteBitcodeToFile` call, but this doesn't work as expected.

How would I write the Module back to IR, and then compile and run the modified IR?

```
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h>
#include <llvm/Support/FileSystem.h>

using namespace llvm;
int main()
{
  LLVMContext context;
  SMDiagnostic error;
  std::unique_ptr<Module> m = parseIRFile("test.ir", error, context);

  std::error_code EC;
  llvm::raw_fd_ostream OS("module", EC, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
  WriteBitcodeToFile(m.get(), OS);
  OS.flush();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work as expected"?

Comment: When I open the file, the contents seem binary?

Comment: @Shuzheng That's just the binary encoding of the IR. You can use `llvm-dis` to get the textual IR, but you should be able to use `llc` directly on the binary to create an object file.

Comment: @TantanLlama: But, can't I write the textual IR back out? I don't want something encoded.

Comment: `Module` has an output operator for `raw_ostream`, so you should be able to just `OS << *m;`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: Why modify IR? If you want to modify _logic_, you should be using [libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) to access the AST.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do it is dumping your module to stdout using:

```
m->dump();
```

Then you can redirect the output of your C++ program to a text file and compile it using *llc* :

```
llc  < sample_module.ll > sample_module.s
```

You can also use the print function:

```
void print (raw_ostream &OS, AssemblyAnnotationWriter *AAW, bool ShouldPreserveUseListOrder=false, bool IsForDebug=false) const
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to write an LLVM pass which allows you to go through the code Function by Function/Module by Module and read/modify/write to it. You can run this pass on your bytecode file using `opt` command and it will return the modified bytecode file which you can use.

Here are some sources for writing a pass:

1) http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

2) https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html

Comment: Will the opt command return a bitcode file with inserted instructions etc? Does this happen automatically if I insert instructions in a basic block?

Comment: Yes, if you write your LLVM pass such that it inserts instruction in the LLVM bytecode then running that pass using ```opt``` will return modified bytecode. Here ```opt```is used to just run your pass on the bytecode. For example look at the section under 'Now Make the Pass Do Something Mildly Interesting' on this page - https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html . Here the example replaces a ```+``` operation with a ```*``` operation using the module pass.

Comment: You can also use ```clang``` to run the pass by using a combination of -Xclang and -load flags

Comment: thank you! Your second resource is much better than the first imo. A bit off-topic, but do you know what "opt" stands for?

Comment: I am not sure but it might mean 'optimizer'

Comment: Using clang, is the output then an executable file instead of bitcode?

Comment: Yes, like it's showed in that example. You can also get the executable by passing the modified bytecode file from opt

Answer (score 0):

IR is not human readable. You can use `llvm-dis` to convert it to the human readable version like @TartanLlama said. You can run bitcode using `lli` command. After you modify the IR, you will see your modified IR running with `lli`.

Comment: The IR is human readable? It looks like x86 assembly in my opinion with statements like alloca, store and ret?

Comment: They were talking about bitcode, usually `IR` is for the memory representation though.

Comment: It's not pretty, but LLVM IR and even Assembly are "human-readable" after getting used to it. The bitcode representation is another story.